# IEnumerable select all except string

Tags: c#

In a part of my code, I'm converting an `IEnumerable` list to a string.

```
String.Join(", ", e.User.Roles.Select(o => o.ToString()))
```

resolves to for example:

```
Admin, @everyone
```

This is using Discord.Net SDK where Roles is an `IEnumerable` containing all the 'ranks' of the user.

There's a default role that every user is apart of which I want to remove from the string. The default role can be called by using

```
e.Server.EveryoneRole
```

My idea was to use `Except` to filter the default role which resulted to

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__72`1[System.Char], System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__72`1[System.Char]
```

or just simply filtering out `@everyone` is also good in my case.

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: Where are you seeing that?  In the debugger?  The debugger is not a great place to see the results of a Linq query - you'd need to materialize it to a List or some other structure.

Comment: What is the type of `e.User.Roles`? Can you also show your code? Especially the `.Except(...)` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use a `where`, such as the following?

```
String.Join(", ", e.User.Roles
                        .Where(o => o != e.Server.EveveryoneRole)
                        .Select(o => o.ToString()))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using where, worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use a line Where clause.
Something like:

```
String.Join(", ", e.User.Roles.Select(o => o.ToString()).Where(s => s != e.Server.EveveryoneRole)
```